# How to point to the position/index of entries of a Fortran array?

Tags: fortran

I have an array of integers (rank 1) let's say:

```
 IDg = (/ 1 , 3, 5, 9 /)
```

Every number is unique (not repeated) in that array.

I need something, let's say another array, which tells me at which position I can find the entries. Basically I need something like

```
 LinearPosition = (/ 1  0  2  0  3  0  0  0  5 /)
```

so that if I need to know at which position I will find the IDg = 5 I will type

```
LinearPosition(5)
```

which will give me the answer 3.

Of course there are many way to "skin a cat", I can of course really build an array like `LinearPosition` , but I think it will be very inefficient (especially if the values of `IDg` are very big).

I don't know why, I have the feeling pointers may be helpful, but I don't know them so well.

Comment: rather, it made me think about hash map, or sparse array. If IDg is sorted you can implement a binary search...

Comment: Thank you for the input, you are actually right. I didn't know anything about hash map and I never thought at the problem of sparse arrays (I never used them in Fortran, just in Matlab).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This expression

```
pack([(ix,ix=1,size(idg))],idg==5)
```

will return a rank-1 array containing the indices into `idg` of the location(s) of the integer `5`.  If it is unique then, of course, the array returned will have only 1 element.

Another approach, as you indicate, is to create an index to `idg` where `idg(index(i))==i`.

The merits, elegance, efficiency, *etc*, of these approaches, and others that might be proposed, depend on many factors: sparsity *vs* density, rate of update *vs* rate of enquiry, eye-of-the-beholder, *etc*.

If you happen to have a Fortran 2008 compiler you can, of course, use the new intrinsic function `findloc`.

Comment: Thank you Mark.
Actually this is exactly the way I usually do (I learned this trick in one of your posts).

Answer (score 0):

Actually I was wondering if a solution like the following would be a little bit more efficient (in terms of memory requirements):

```
type :: punt_index
       integer(i4), pointer :: ptr
end type punt_index

type(punt_index), allocatable :: linear_position(:)

do i= 1,size(IDg)
     allocate(linear_position(IDg(i))%ptr)
     linear_position(IDg(i))%ptr = i  
end do
```

In this way, only an array of the same dimensions of IDg has to be stored, besides of course the array of pointers (which maybe is not "expensive").
What do you think about it?

Comment: Efficiency is not something I **ever** wonder about.  When efficiency is a concern I measure.